# Optional Input Values in SUP Personalization Parameters(iOS)

Tags: iphone, parameters, nullable, sup

I am creating an iPhone application with SUP. I am using SAP as my datasource.In my MBO s I created some personalization parameters not any synchronization parameters.Some of them are optional inputs.For eg I have an MBO for approving purchase orders.I can approve them with or without comments.Here comment field personalization parameter is a Nullable (optional)parameter and PO_Num  parameter is not NUllable.My problem is when I approve a purchase order with comment my comment field is not inputted to the server.But approval is doing fine.I have this problem in other MBO s also.I am sure that I am setting the comment personalization parameter from my application.This issue is happening only in iOS.Because my android colleague using same MBO s in android.He had not such issues.I am using SUP 2.1.3.

I am new to SUP
Any help is appreciable
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to give you a comment on your question because don't have enough reputation to give a comment.

if you are using SUP then you would used http://sdn.sap.com forums for mobile questions and answers. I also used the same for SUP related question.

Answer (score 0):

You must give each MBO input a default value. Otherwise your MBO request will not process the way you are thinking.
When you want the comment PP to be null. Save it explicitly while working native on Xcode.